# How to create nested type of data in Python?

Tags: python, oop

I want to make sure, that one of the arguments, passed when class creation is of certain type. Here is an example:

```py
from __future__ import annotations
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass(frozen=True, order=True)
class ListItems:
    items: list | str | int | ListItems


class PList:
    def __init__(self, name: str, items: ListItems):
        self.type = "list"
        self.name = name
        self.items = items


a = PList('asd', ['asd'])
```

The idea was next: `items` can only be list of `string`, `int` data type **or other list** of `string` and `int`, and it's nested. For example:

```
[] OK
[1,2,'asd'] OK
[[1,2,3],'asd',[]] OK
[{}] NOT OK
['test', [{}]] NOT OK
```

Is it possible to implement something like this in Python?

I am not really familiar with Python OOP, but from what I have found, there is no native implementation of interfaces and/or abstract class like in other programming languages.

PS:
The code you see, was just my attempt of implementation, it did not work.

Comment: Do you want that the type of the argument is checked at runtime or by static checkers (e.g. mypy), or both?

Comment: You could check for the type and allow or not based on that??

Comment: @mkrieger1 Actually, only at runtime

Comment: @dokichan then **why are you asking about type hints**?

Answer (score 0):

`def __init__(self, name: str, items: ListItems):`

the `items: ListItems` bit is saying that `items` should be a `ListItems` object, it's not passing through the logic of what `ListItems` is doing, it's literally just comparing what type it is.

i don't have much experience with typing, but i think you're looking for `items: list[str|int]` note that for lists, there is the normal list type hint, and then there's also one in the typing library. not sure if there's a difference, i just know that the normal list type hint is lowercased (`list` and not `List` like in the typing library), and that it is relatively new (3.11 i think)

Comment: Problem here, is that if you have `items: list[str | int]` you can put object in this list. Like this: `a = PList('asd', ['asd', {}])`, and it will work

Comment: yeah i'm not sure then friend. i would just say that's the area that you'd be looking for. maybe creating a class and inheriting the capital L `List` from the typing library, you could change some behavior

Comment: just to be clear, are you looking for typing errors like the yellow underlines in an IDE or are you looking to raise an exception if the type is wrong? because type hinting doesn't raise exceptions

Comment: @dokichan of *course*, these are type hints. They won't be enforced at runtime. Also `{}` is a `dict`, not an "object" (well, it *is* an object, but **everything** is an object)

Comment: @Nate No, inheriting from `typing.List` won't change anything and in any case, `typing.List` is deprecated.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga "these are type hints. They won't be enforced at runtime." I agree with you I mentioned that in the answer I posted it.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer to your question **Python** is a **dynamically typed** language. It doesn’t know about the type of the variable until the code is run. So declaration is of no use. What it does is, It stores that value at some memory location and then binds that variable name to that memory container. And makes the contents of the container accessible through that variable name. So the data type does not matter. As it will get to know the type of the value at run-time.

**Names are bound to objects at execution time** by means of assignment statements, and it is possible to bind a name to objects of different types during the execution of the program. **Functions and objects** can be altered at runtime.

> In a dynamically typed language, a variable is simply a value bound to
> a name; the value has a type -- like "integer" or "string" or "list"
> -- but the variable itself doesn't. You could have a variable which, right now, holds a number, and later assign a string to it if you need
> it to change. In a statically typed language, the variable itself has
> a type; if you have a variable that's an integer, you won't be able to
> assign any other type of value to it later.

From the following point you will find that predefining the datatype explicitly in python code won't enforce it to only accept this type:

> (since type errors are a small fraction of all the things that might go wrong in a program); as a result, programmers in dynamic languages rely on their test
> suites to catch these and all other errors, rather than using a
> dedicated type-checking compiler.

Check this [reference](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Why%20is%20Python%20a%20dynamic%20language%20and%20also%20a%20strongly%20typed%20language) for more info.

Comment: I don't agree that there is "no point". There are a lot of good reasons to use type hints, and furthermore, you can use a static type checker to verify the type correctness of your code.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I mean that predefining the datatype using type hint will not enforce python interpreter to only accept this datatype for the variable since it will know the type at run-time.

Comment: Sure, but that isn't the same thing as saying "there is no point".

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure you even need the class listItems. Just use a simple if statement in your init method.

```
class PList:
  def __init__(self, name, items):
    self.type = 'list'
    self.name = name
    if type(items) is list or type(items) is str or type(items) is int:
      self.items = items
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but type hinting is a thing, and it works quite similarly to typescript